# Date/Time Picker Jquery, Prototype, anything?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have a date/time field that I need to have a date/time picker but it's near impossible finding one, a decent one (I have googled like wild).  I tried this picker http://electronicholas.com/calendar but it's in Ruby on Rails and I do not know how to convert it.  Any ideas?  I run mainly jquery but I would use another lib if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

another: http://www.dynarch.com/static/jscalendar-1.0/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have seen this one before but it does not do time, it does date but I need both for the same input box.

Comment: The dynarch supports time, look again.  It's even on the page I've linked.

and adding time to the format of the textbox you have a calendar wrapped around isn't too hard: http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/adding-time-to-jquery-ui-datepicker/

Comment: totally blew that one I did, sorry about that rball;)

Answer (score 2):

Article 10 Best jQuery Datepickers Plugins
http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-jquery-datepickers-plugins

Another datepicker from Google web elements. It's easy to use.

http://www.google.com/webelements/calendar/

Answer (score 0):

The [Any+Time™ DatePicker/TimePicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) supports date+time fields with a wide range of formats.  It uses jQuery (including jQuery UI Themes) and allows for extensive CSS customization, custom labels and many other options.  Most importantly, it is perhaps the fastest and easiest combo-picker available, because it uses simple buttons to select all values (no sloppy sliders, spinners or drop-down boxes) and also supports WAI-ARIA keyboard accessibility.  Oh, and did I mention it is FREE under the CC-BY-NC-SA license? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the bootstrap datepicker plugin? I currently use it on my site and it looks really good IMO. you can also configure it to show dates, times etc. If you're interested, this is the tutorial i followed to set it up http://develop.alpdesigns.ch/pages/other/bootstrap-datepicker.html